# How can I get the index of the highest number in an Object[] in an ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

How can I find the highest value or the index of the highest value in the object in the arrayList shown below.

I attempted to iterate the ArrayList but it takes the whole object and I need each element. Any help is appreciated thanks

[image: ArrayList With Object Iteration]

Comment: Question is not clear , please provide more details .

Comment: Yeah, all that data is shown there.

Comment: It's 18 elements long, and the last entry is there of you pan over.

Comment: Don't see how it was unclear when  lltis read it and gave an answer that worked first time

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right you could use something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    Object array[] = arrayList.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
       // compare here
    }
}
```

First iterate over the arrayList and then over each array.

Comment: You read my question perfectly and your answer works perfect thanks very much I tried multiple ways but could not get it right, I tried to plus one it but I do not have 15 reputation sorry